# It takes longer to transact your money Bitcoin! Why?

Tags: transactions, confirmations

When it says transactions takes up to 10 minutes, Why do it take more then two minutes when you transfer money into another account

Comment: Related: [What are bitcoin "confirmations"?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/146/what-are-bitcoin-confirmations) and [How secure is zero confirmations?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/20845/how-secure-is-zero-confirmations)

Answer (score 2):

On average, it is always ten minutes until the next bitcoin block will be mined. However, there are ways to transact bitcoin without waiting for a bitcoin transaction that includes your payment to be included in a block. For example, you can use the [lightning network](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/48283/what-is-the-lightning-network-proposal-what-problem-is-it-trying-to-solve), which allows near-instant payment confirmation for network participants.

Technologies like the lightning network move payments to a 'higher level' network, which is made secure by the strong settlement guarantees of the bitcoin network. Waiting 10-30 minutes for settlements that reconcile a huge number of individual payments from the higher level network is a much more reasonable architecture, compared to waiting 10-30 minutes for each and every payment to confirm.