# Clarification of lightning network example (putting funds into lightning)

Tags: lightning-network, ln-opening-channels

I'm checking [How does the Lightning network work in simple terms?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/43700/how-does-the-lightning-network-work-in-simple-terms) answer example:

> 1) Putting funds into Lightning  We both send 0.5 BTC into a shared
>   2-of-2 multisig address. This requires a transaction on the Bitcoin
>   blockchain.  As a "balance sheet", we each create a 2-of-2 multisig
>   transaction that pays out 0.5 BTC to you and 0.5 BTC to me. I sign
>   one payout transaction and give it to you. If you want to put it in
>   effect, you need only add your own signature and broadcast it to the
>   Bitcoin network. Vice versa, you give me your copy of the payout
>   transaction that you have signed and I have not yet. The "balance
>   sheet" is a regular 2-of-2 multisig transaction in the Bitcoin
>   network, it just isn't valid yet, because it doesn't have all
>   signatures.

So in the first step you make **a regular transaction** from your address A to our common 2-2 address C, and I make **a regular transaction** from my address B to our common 2-2 address C?

I have one key of this 2-2 multisig address C and you have another?

Address C now has 1BTC.

Now **from this address C** I return 0.5 of its 1 BTC **to your address A** and sign with my key, and you return remaining 0.5 **to my address B** and sign with your key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So in the first step you make a regular transaction from your address A to our common 2-2 address C, and I make a regular transaction from my address B to our common 2-2 address C?

Yes, although in the current lightning spec and implementation, only one party funds the channel. However it could certainly be both parties that fund it.

> I have one key of this 2-2 multisig address C and you have another?

Yes.

> Address C now has 1BTC.
>
> Now from this address C I return 0.5 of its 1 BTC to your address A and sign with my key, and you return remaining 0.5 to my address B and sign with your key?

Two transactions are formed at this point:

- one that you make and sign and send to me that gives 0.5 BTC to you and 0.5 BTC to me,
- one that I make and sign and send to you that also gives 0.5 BTC to you and 0.5 BTC to me.

Comment: Regarding third part. I know that both must sign to be valid. I'm interested if in the second step we use the address C (we put funds in step one) to return funds?

Comment: Yes, address C is the one that is spent from to return funds.

Comment: Also in the third part, the transaction I make from 2-2 address has two outputs (0.5 to me and 0.5 to you), or just one output that sends 0.5BTC to you?

Comment: It is two outputs

Comment: And the transaction you make from 2-2 address has also two outputs 0.5 to me and 0.5 to you? Thus only one of these transactions can be fullfiled, as each spends entire funds from address C?

Comment: No. Address C has 1 BTC, and the transaction spends that 1 BTC and sends 0.5 to me and 0.5 to you.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68778/room-for-croraf-and-andrew-chow